# Не могу понять почему блоки не выравниваются в одну линию, заголовок стал нормально, а остальной текст ниже

Tags: html, css

HTML
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CSS

```
body{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium','Gilroy-Bold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 944px;
}
.header-nav{
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-item{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #828282;
    padding: 32px 0;
}

.nav-item:hover{
    color: #070707;
}

.header-hr{
    color: #828282;
    border: 1px solid #828282;
    transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

.header-inner{
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 59px;
    color: #070707;
}

.header-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    color: #070707;
}

.header-info{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;

}

.header-text{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Medium';
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

.header_changer{
    font-family: 'Gilroy-Bold';
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #828282;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

[image: как выглядит у меня]
[image: как должно быть]

Comment: Если я правильно понял проблему, то в `.header-info` вместо `align-items: flex-end` укажите `align-items: baseline`

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).

Comment: К сожалению не могу прикрепить скриншот, при значении align-items: baseline, блоки выровнялись по имени denis, но все равно ушли ниже, но после того как убрал теги <br> всё выравнивается как раз по нижней линии, только не знаю как теперь заменить <br>, чтобы расположение текста осталось такое же.

Comment: Спасибо, хоть немного теперь приблизился к решению проблемы.

Comment: А вы обнулили `margin` для `h1`?

Comment: @Гога не baeline, а align-items: center;

Comment: @ΝNL993 У меня почему-то не выводился html код текстом

Comment: @Oliver Patterson Я подключил hormalize.css там выставлен margin 0, для всего body

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи align-imes: center выравнивает по центру, а мне нужно чтобы блоки выровнялись по нижней строке, конечно baseline выравнивает практически также, но если прописан тег <br>

Comment: @Гога тогда flex-end

Comment: У вас правильно всё написано, просто языки справа у вас вертикально стоят, вам нужно добавить ещё translate(число, число). Оно может вставляться в тот же transform, где и rotate(),  - transform: translate(10px, 10px) rotate(90deg);

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи , Спасибо, с помощью translate всё заработало, а так вообще можно делать с точки зрения правильности кода, я просто новичок, многих моментов не знаю.

Comment: @Гога когда вы rotate используете, он уже не подчиняется никакой сетке, так как параметры ширины и высоты не работают стандартно - если текста прибавится, он будет расширяться в высоту, а значит придётся поправлять стили. Поэтому такое применять в основном следует только на не меняющиеся по ширине и высоте элементы.

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое.